# Выполнение потока Asynctask в цикле

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

Делаю приложение на Android. Пытаюсь сделать в цикле вызов выполнения потока `Asynctask`, но проблема в том что при выполнении цикла поток не прекращается и происходит дальше выполнение кода до того как поток завершен.

Например:

```
for (int i =0; i<array.size; i++)
{
             ......(код)

  new MyAsynctask().execute();

             ......(код)

}
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

где  сам Asynctask:

```
     class MyAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
     super.onPreExecute();
     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
     pDialog.setMessage("Loading!!!");
     pDialog.setCancelable(false);
     pDialog.show();

     }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

          ...........  (вся тяжелая работа)

        }

     }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

     super.onPostExecute(result);
     if (pDialog.isShowing())
     pDialog.dismiss();
     }
```

При таком коде асинктаск вызывается в цикле начинает выполняться и сразу за ним начинает выполняться код в UI даже если асинктаск не закончил работу.
Я хочу чтобы асинктаск выполнялся до конца затем выполнялся последовательно дальнейший код и после прохождения (завершения) всего цикла выполнялся переход в другое активити. Это можно сделать с методом get().

```
      new MyAsynctask().execute().get();
```

вроде все работает таким образом но проблема в том что UI поток останавливается тогда до того момента как Asynctask поток завершится. То есть на дисплее не происходит никаких действий (мне нужно чтобы Progress Bar крутился).

Писать :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

в `onPostExecute();` тоже не подходит так как Asynctask вызывается в несколько раз в цикле. А мне нужно вызов Activity вызвать только один раз после завершения цикла.

Может есть возможность в ручную сделать прогресс бар при выполнении метода `get()`?
Какие есть еще варианты?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вам такой огород с AsyncTask'ами и циклом? Вашим способом не получиться добиться того, чего вы хотите. Либо у вас будут запущено множество AsyncTask'ов, без ожидания завершения предыдущего, либо у вас будет заблокирован UI. Если вы так хотите использовать AsyncTask, то выносите всю работу в 1 AsyncTask без всяких циклов.

Еще как один из вариантов это запустить service, а после завершения работы выслать Broadcast, поймать его в Activity1 и запустить Activity2.

**Edit:**

Почему бы не зделать примерно так:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AssyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        //пформируем результат
        while(true){
            String string = getHtmString();
            builder.append(string);
        }

         return builder.toString();
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //здесь обрабатываете результат
     }
}
```

**Edit2:**

Создаете так же как и в цикле, только один экзэмпляр, и всю работу переносите в `doInBackground()` . Так же можете зделать отдельно класс, в котором будет происходить вся работа, и у которого будет публичный метод, который возвращает результат. И всю вашу логику по получению результата переносите туда, в а `doInBAckground()` вызываете только метод этого класса. Должно получиться примерно следующее:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AssyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        HtmlUtils htmlUtils = new HtmlUtils();

         return htmlUtils.getResult();
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //здесь обрабатываете результат
     }
}

public class HtmlUtils(){


    //some code

    public String getResult(){//some code}
}
```

А в активити вызываете `new MyAsyncTask().execute(null);`

Comment: спасибо за ответ. но у меня проблема в том что я из каждого выполненного асинктаска получаю в результате String в виде HTML кода  который ссумирую со стрингом из предыдущего законченного асинктаска и в итоге должен быть в конечном итоге один общий String  html который я хочу показать в Webview в другом Activity

Comment: Думаю что можно сделать цикл не UI потоке а в самом асинктаске и интент вызвать в самом onpostexecute  но тогда вопрос как сделать асинктаск в отдельном классе и вызывать его в главном активити. Так как у меня много кода в doinbackground.

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток!

Подобную проблему я решаю следующим образом:

1. Создаем процедуру, которая будет выбирать первый элемент массива и отправлять его в обработку или, в случае завершения массива, выполнять какие-то действия:

   ```
   public void OnStartOperation(){
       if((array != null) && (array.size > 0)){
           String item = array.get(0);
           ... Код предобработки ...
           new MyAsynctask().execute();
       } else {
           ... Код завершения обработки цикла ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Изменяем AsincTask следующим образом (только onPostExecute):

   ```
   @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           if (pDialog.isShowing())
           pDialog.dismiss();

           // Удаляем отработанную запись
           if((array != null) && (array.size() > 0){
               array.remove(0);
           }
           // Стартуем следующую итерацию
           OnStartOperation();
       }
   ```

Надеюсь, поможет.

Comment: спасибо не плохой вариант. но тогда array удаляется и нельзя его повторно использовать. дело в том что у меня этот цикл (или OnStartOperation()) вызывается при помощи кнопки Onclick. То есть тогда все сработает но только один раз

Comment: В таком случае просто выполните дублирование массива по нажатию кнопки и отправляйте на обработку дубликат.

Answer (score 1):

Тут либо всю работу, которая в цикле исполняется сразу вынести в АсинкТаск, либо, если именно надо создать 100500 АсинкТасков и дождаться их исполнения, тогда лучше использовать [Thread Executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077771/only-one-thread-at-a-time)
Только тогда в цикле надо будет создавать не АсинкТаски а Runnable-ы, которые в Executor отправляются на выполнение. Executor управляет выполнением созданных работ, возможно 1 за одним, если так надо, можно пачками, там по 5. И в конце, как все ранейблы отработают - переход в другое активити.